# How can I extend a validation field into a PIVOT table?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a sheet with different columns and one of them is a validated field. From that sheet I create a PIVOT table. When I double click on an item of the PIVOT table to expand it however, I find that all the columns are there but the validated field is not a validated field anymore. Is there a way that I can extend this field so that the validated field appears after I expand an item from the PIVOT table?

Thank you